# Javacc : one input accepted by two rules

Tags: compiler-construction, javacc

i have a grammar file in javacc which is as follows :

```
    TOKEN : {
        <STRING_LITERAL : ( "\"" ~ ["\"","\\"] | "\\" (
         ["n","t","b","r","f","\\","\'","\""] | ["0"-"7"] (["0"-"7"])? | ["0"-"3"] ["0"-"7"]
         ["0"-"7"] | ( ["\n","\r"] | "\r\n")))* "\""> 
    }
```

and a production rule which checks for a particular pattern of string_litral
i.e

```
    void rangearg():{}
    {
        <DQUOTE> rangearg1() <DQUOTE>
    }

    void rangearg1():{}
    {
        rangepart() ("|" rangepart())* 
    }
    void rangepart():{}
    {
        rangeboundary()[ ".." rangeboundary()]
    }
    void rangeboundary():{}
    {
       <MIN> | <MAX> |  <ZERO> |(<INTVALUE>)+(<INTVALUE1>)* | <MINUS> ((<INTVALUE>)+)(<INTVALUE1>)*
    }
```

Now my problem is : whenever it encounters a string of the form  it gives an error saying
   Encountered "STRING_LITERAL" at line XX column XX ,Expected "\""
Is there a way to handle this error?

Comment: Could you clarify what the language rules are? Your language is ambiguous in the sense that something like `"0..max"`, for example, could be interpreted as 1 token or as 5. What are the exact rules for determining how an input like this should be tokenized?  Is there a language reference manual that you can refer to?

Comment: I am writing a grammar file for Yang data modelling language. Please refer to the RFC 6020 document https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6020 for its grammar rules which are written in abnf grammar.

Comment: Whenever it encounters a string of the form <DQUOTE> <rangearg> <DQUOTE>, it gives an error because <STRING_LITERAL> also matches to the rule and also because the order is a criteria here. I've referred to the javacc faq 4.19 but couldn't understand it. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest is that you parse the range statement with something like the following.

```
void rangeStatement() : }{
    Token tk ;
} {
    <RANGE>
    tk=<STRING_LITERAL>
    { reparse( tk.image ) ; }
    ...
}
```

I.e. accept any string as a range string and then parse the contents of the range string with a second parser.

Comment: I understood the idea behind what you are trying to explain but I am not able to implement it since I am new to javacc. Could you please write down the reparse() function? What do you mean by a second parser? @Theodore Norvell                                                                              Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well if I'm reading the RFC correctly (and I didn't spend a lot of time reading it), the string that comes after the keyword range is just a string in terms of the tokenization rules for the language. Here is an analogy. In Java strings are just tokens, but if you want to know what a string "means" you have to 'parse' the image of the string's token. In Java this is mostly a matter of dealing with backslashes, so it's fairly simple. In Yang the range strings have a more complex syntax, but the idea is the same. This second parser --the range string parser-- could be written in JavaCC or not.